# Undefined variable answers eventhough variable is defined

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php

class Question_model extends CI_Model {
  public $answers;

  public function filter_answers($value){
    if(is_string($value))
    {
      if(strpos($value,"option") !== false){
        $this->$answers[] = str_replace("option","",$value);
      }
    }
  }
  public function create_question($data){
      $data = array(
        'explanation' => $data['exp'],
        'name' => $data['name']
      );

      $this->db->insert('question', $data);

      array_filter($data,array($this,"filter_answers"));
      echo $this->$answers;
  }
}
```

I am using codeigniter framework and i am getting this in model as you can see that variable is actually defined and not the other way around. I am calling model from codeigniter controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be call **answer** property with **`$this->answers`**, not by `$this->$answers`.

```
<?php

class Question_model extends CI_Model {
  public $answers;

  public function filter_answers($value){
    if(is_string($value))
    {
      if(strpos($value,"option") !== false){
        $this->answers[] = str_replace("option","",$value);
      }
    }
  }
  public function create_question($data){
      $data = array(
        'explanation' => $data['exp'],
        'name' => $data['name']
      );

      $this->db->insert('question', $data);

      array_filter($data,array($this,"filter_answers"));
      echo $this->answers;
  }
}
```

Comment: but in php documentation it is given as $this->$property

Comment: No problem. Please accept this answer, if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

> The double arrow operator, “=>”, is used as an access mechanism for
>   arrays. This means that what is on the left side of it will have a
>   corresponding value of what is on the right side of it in array
>   context. This can be used to set values of any acceptable type into a
>   corresponding index of an array. The index can be associative (string
>   based) or numeric.

```
<?php
$myArray = array(
 0 => 'Big',
 1 => 'Small',
 2 => 'Up',
 3 => 'Down'
 );
 ?>
```

> The object operator, “->”, is used in object scope to access methods
>   and properties of an object. It’s meaning is to say that what is on
>   the right of the operator is a member of the object instantiated into
>   the variable on the left side of the operator. Instantiated is the key
>   term here.

```
  <?php
    $obj = new MyObject(); // Create a new instance of MyObject into $obj
    $obj->thisProperty = 'Fred'; // Set a property in the $obj object called thisProperty
    $obj->getProperty(); // Call a method of the $obj object named getProperty
    ?>
```

**Example**

```
<?php

class Question_model extends CI_Model {
  public $answers;

  public function filter_answers($value){
    if(is_string($value))
    {
      if(strpos($value,"option") !== false){
        $this->answers[] = str_replace("option","",$value);
      }
    }
  }
  public function create_question($data){
      $data = array(
        'explanation' => $data['exp'],
        'name' => $data['name']
      );

      $this->db->insert('question', $data);

      array_filter($data,array($this,"filter_answers"));
      echo $this->answers;
  }
}
```